# Google sheets nested if formula, different for two digits and three digits?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula in google sheets that is

```
=IF(H7<-3,0.95*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*1.01))
```

This should only be if F7 is three digits and more. I'd like to add a condition further that if F7 is two digits or less (under 100) then it should be

```
=IF(H7<-3,0.9*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*.95))
```

How to combine both of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the digits of a number you can actually calculate the length of the number. However, there are three possible scenarios based on what you want to achieve and what is your input; float number or integer:

---

If you want to calculate the number of digits of a **float** number **after the decimal point** (seperated by ".") use that:

```
=if(LEN(RIGHT(F7,LEN(F7)-FIND(".",F7))) >2,IF(H7<-3,0.95*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*1.01)),IF(H7<-3,0.9*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*.95)))
```

---

If you want to calculate the total number of digits of a **float** number **before and after** the decimal point (seperated by ".") use that:

```
 =if(len(F7)-1>2,IF(H7<-3,0.95*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*1.01)),IF(H7<-3,0.9*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*.95)))
```

---

If you want to calculate the total number of digits of an **integer** then use:

```
=if(len(F7)>2,IF(H7<-3,0.95*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*1.01)),IF(H7<-3,0.9*F7,IF(H7<3,F7,F7*.95)))
```

Based on your question I assume you need the last scenario, so pick up yourself whatever it suits you the best.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(LEN(F7*1)<3, 
 IF(H7 < -3, 0.9*F7,  IF(H7 < 3,F7, F7*.95)), 
 IF(H7 < -3, 0.95*F7, IF(H7 < 3,F7, F7*1.01)))
```